# Copy a full DBGrid(structure and Data) to KbmMemTable

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I wanna copy created `TXDBGrid`a full structure (columns) whith exist data in this Grid to `kbmMemTable`.

Comment: Your grid is populated from some sort of dataset (can't be from *many*) - copy from there.

Comment: My fault i say about main table. I just wanna get a mirror of `Grid`/`dataset` to `kbmMemTable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `TDBGrid` descendant and similar components are a "visualization" of a data set, represented by a `TDataset` descendant component (`TTable`, `TQuery`,...).  `TDBGrid` it's a way to represent data.

You can't build the structure in a `kbmMemTable` from `TDBGrid`, yes from `TDataset` associated with that grid.

The component `kbmMemTable` has this method:

```
procedure LoadFromDataSet(Source:TDataSet;
   CopyOptions:TkbmMemTableCopyTableOptions); 
   {$IFDEF BCB}dynamic{$ELSE}virtual{$ENDIF};
```

The source parameter is the `TDataset` associated to your grid, and the second parameter include options to copy the structure of source `TDataset` (`mtcpoStructure`).

```
TkbmMemTableCopyTableOption = 
  mtcpoStructure,mtcpoOnlyActiveFields,mtcpoProperties,
  mtcpoLookup,mtcpoCalculated,mtcpoAppend,mtcpoFieldIndex,
  mtcpoDontDisableIndexes,mtcpoIgnoreErrors
  {$IFDEF LEVEL6},mtcpoStringAsWideString,mtcpoWideStringUTF8{$ENDIF});
```

Try some like this:

```
  kbmMemTable1.LoadFromDataSet(XDBGrid1.Datasource.DataSet, [mtcpoStructure]);
```